# Stop Bootstrap Wrapping

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

As I resize the width of my browser, I notice that my "Stage" list items collapse and stack on one another. I know that is default behavior, but I would like them to disappear at a certain width. Right now, the right most column collapses before all the columns disappear. I want them to disappear before they collapse. Can someone show me how to do that? I could not figure out how to use get the media query (if needed) to work in jsFiddle, so it is below. The rest of the markup is in jsFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/6dFSS/

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1025px){
.container {
    width: 95%;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

.navbar-default {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
}

@media screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
#header {
    font-size: 80%;
}

.navbar-default {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
h3 {
    font-size: 70%;
}

.navbar-default {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured it out. The key to making sure that rows collapse before they wrap is to make sure you have your media queries set up properly to use the varying resolutions that are available. At the very least, the ones you are targeting.

Ensure your padding and margins are at 0 in the container you want to control. This way, you get a true layout of the width. Then assemble all of the media queries you will need. Here are the media queries used by bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/css/.

Below are the media queries I am now using. I added one from my original question so I could get tighter control as to how the markup changes as the viewport changes. If your markup is wrapping before you get to a resolution that will collapse it, find the resolution that the markup will fit in without collapsing. In IE 11, if you hit F12 for the developer tools, you can find a list of popular resolutions and the viewport size.

```
/************************************************************************************
1366 and higher
*************************************************************************************/
@media screen and (min-width: 1366px){
    .container {
        width: 75%;
        margin: 0;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        padding: 0;
        border: solid 1px #AABDCB;
    }
}

/************************************************************************************
1025 up to 1365
*************************************************************************************/
@media screen and (min-width: 1025px) and (max-width: 1365px){
    .container {
        width: 95%;
        margin: 0;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        padding: 0;
        border: solid 1px #AABDCB;
    }
}

/************************************************************************************
smaller than 1024
*************************************************************************************/
@media screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .container {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
}

/************************************************************************************
smaller than 480
*************************************************************************************/
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .container {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
}
```